# Tensorflow, Keras and GPUS: logs show Resource Exhausted Error before simply loading up model weights

Tags: performance, memory, tensorflow, keras

I am new to Ubuntu and I am setting up a new machine for deep learning using Keras and Tensorflow. I am fine tuning VGG16 on a set of pretty complex medical images. My machine specifications are:-

```
i7-6900K CPU @ 3.20GHz × 16  
GeForce GTX 1080 Ti x 4
62.8 GiB of RAM
```

My previous machine was an iMac with no GPU but an i7 quad core processor and 32GB of RAM. The iMac ran the following model although it took 32 hours to complete it.

Here is the code:-

```
  img_width, img_height = 512, 512
  top_model_weights_path = '50435_train_uip_possible_inconsistent.h5'
  train_dir = '../../MasterHRCT/50435/Three-Classes/train'
  validation_dir =  '../../MasterHRCT/50435/Three-Classes/validation'
  nb_train_samples = 50435
  nb_validation_samples = 12600
  epochs = 200
  batch_size = 16

  datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
  model = applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
```

Then:-

```
generator_train = datagen.flow_from_directory(
train_dir, 
target_size=(img_width, img_height), 
shuffle=False, 
class_mode=None,
batch_size=batch_size
)  

bottleneck_features_train = model.predict_generator(
generator=generator_train, 
steps=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
verbose=1
)

np.save(file="50435_train_uip_possible_inconsistent.npy",     arr=bottleneck_features_train)
print("Completed train data")

generator_validation = datagen.flow_from_directory(
validation_dir, 
target_size=(img_width, img_height), 
shuffle=False, 
class_mode=None,
batch_size=batch_size
)  

bottleneck_features_validation = model.predict_generator(
generator=generator_validation, 
steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size,
verbose=1
)

np.save(file="12600_validate_uip_possible_inconsistent.npy", arr=bottleneck_features_validation)
print("Completed validation data")
```

Yesterday, I ran this code and it was super fast (nvidia-smi suggested that only one GPU was being used which I believe is expected for TF). The CPU hit 56% of maximum. Then it crashed - with a `CUDA_OUT_OF_MEMORY` error. So I lowered the batch size to 4. Again, its started really fast but then the CPU jumped to 100% and my system froze. I had to hard reboot.

I have tried again today, and the first time I get this error when simply trying to load the ImageNet Weights...

```
  ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[3,3,512,512]
 [[Node: block4_conv2_2/random_uniform/RandomUniform = RandomUniform[T=DT_INT32, dtype=DT_FLOAT, seed=87654321, seed2=5932420, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](block4_conv2_2/random_uniform/shape)]]
```

On the command line it says:-

```
2017-08-08 06:13:57.937723: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime  /bfc_allocator.cc:700] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 71.99MiB
2017-08-08 06:13:57.937739: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:702] Stats: 
Limit:                    80150528
InUse:                    75491072
MaxInUse:                 80069120
NumAllocs:                     177
MaxAllocSize:             11985920
```

Now clearly this is a memory issue - but why would it fail to even load the weights. My Mac can run this entire code albeit intractably slowly. I should note that this morning, I did get this code running once, but this time, it was ridiculously slow - slower than my Mac. My ignorant view is that something is chewing memory but I can't debug this...I am uncertain where to begin being new to Ubuntu. Having the precedence of seeing the code run super fast (and then toward the end crash) yesterday I wonder has the system 'reset' something or disabled something.

Help!

EDIT:

I cleared all the variables in jupyter notebook, dropped the batch size to 1 and reloaded and I managed to load the weights, but on running the first generator I get:

```
    ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1,512,512,64]
 [[Node: block1_conv1/convolution = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](_arg_input_1_0_0/_105, block1_conv1/kernel/read)]]
```

I am not clear why I can succesfully run this on my Mac but not a machine with greater RAM, CPU and 4 GPUs...